# Duplicate Title Tags with Django Pagination

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I've recently deployed my website [infortion](https://infortion.com). On the home page, I've used the django pagination so that users can see more content.

Few days ago I connected the site to `webmasters` & it's showing an error `Duplicate title tags` in the HTML improvements section.

Problem is coming from the home page because pagination is taking the users to next page but still keeping the same `title`. Which means these two pages,

```
/
/?page=2
```

will have the same title.

How can we solve this problem? Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Add a place for a title in your template and override that when passing it your context in the view.